# Como fazer potencias de 9 de forma rápida

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou fazendo uma questão que pede para elevar o numero a 9 e dizer o ultimo digito eu consegui, porém a resolução parece que passou do tempo pois tinha numero de 10^9, como resolver isso de uma forma mais rápida 
Meu código

```
import  math
while True:
  try:
    numero = int(input())
    recebe = pow(9,numero)
    string = str(recebe)
    tam = len(string)
    print(string[tam-1])
except EOFError:
    break
```

Comment: Não precisas de transformar em string nem importar `math`, podes calcular o modulo de 10 para obteres o ultimo digito: https://repl.it/repls/MintyUnconsciousCopyright

Comment: olá miguel, mesmo com essa sua ideia minha resposta ainda não passou

Comment: quais dão os valores e tempo limite com que estás a trabalhar? Carregaste no link do meu comentário acima?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> pede para elevar o numero a 9

Você fala uma coisa e seu código diz outra. Quando faz `pow(9,numero)`, está *elevando 9 a um número*, e não um número a 9. Vamos ver as coisas de dois jeitos.

---

#### Último caractere, elevando um dado número a 9

Abra um arquivo ou prompt python e cole o seguinte:

```
for i in range(100):
    print(i, str(i**9)[-1])
```

O que estamos fazendo é mostrar um número de 0 a 99, e o último dígito desse número quando elevado a 9.

Vai achar um resultado desse tipo:

```
75 5
76 6
77 7
78 8
79 9
80 0
81 1
82 2
83 3
...
```

Consegue enxergar algum padrão aí? *O último dígito de cada número elevado a 9 é o último dígito do próprio número*. Ficou mais fácil, não? Podemos simplificar o bloco de código pro seguinte:

```
numero = input()
print(numero[-1])
```

---

#### Último caractere, elevando 9 a um dado número

Caso o problema seja realmente sobre elevar 9 a um dado número como no seu código, podemos tentar descobrir se há algum outro padrão.

```
for i in range(100):
    print(i, str(9**i)[-1])
```

Resultado:

```
56 1
57 9
58 1
59 9
60 1
61 9
62 1
...
```

Ora ora, Batman. Parece que temos outro padrão. Pra números ímpares a resposta é `9`, e pra pares a resposta é `1`. Nosso código pode ficar assim:

```
numero = int(input())
print(1 if numero % 2 == 0 else 9)
```

Voilá! Resolvemos o problema sem calcular uma única potência.

**Moral da história:** pode valer a pena estudar superficialmente o problema antes de ir pra solução direta.

Answer (score 1):

10 elevado à nona potência parece não ser o problema, o calculo é bem rápido.

Acredito que o `pow` esteja invertido, para elevar um numero à 9 seria ao contrário, `pow(9, numero)`, do jeito que está você está fazendo 9 elevado à N potência.

Precisa desse `while true`? A unica demora executando no meu computador seria isso, porque ele volta para o começo e pede para digitar o numero novamente.

Comment: O inteiro que vai ser elevado a 9 é um numero que 10^9